# Klein quartic (divisor)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coding-theory

help me please with this problem (it's taken from book and I don't know how to prove)

Klein quartic is the curve $ X\subset \mathbb{P}^{2}$ with the homogeneous equation:

$x^{3}y+y^{3}z+z^{3}x=0$

Prove that the divisor of the linear form $z$ on $X$ is $(z)=Q_{1}+3Q_{2}$  where $Q_{1}=(1:0:0)$ and 
$Q_{2}=(0:1:0)$

Thanks!

[Book](http://www.math.umass.edu/~hajir/m499c/tvn-book.pdf)

Comment: Do you know what "divisor" means? What have you tried, and where do you get stuck?

Comment: First you should identify the points, where $z$ vanishes. Then compute the order of the zero. I only know how to do this for function (as opposed to forms). I don't know the definition of the divisor of a form, it appears to be related to the divisor of a function, but the poles are gone.

BTW. Is this from a book on algebraic-geometry codes? Otherwise I have a hard time figuring out why the coding-theory tag is used :-)

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Thanks for the hint! Yes you are right, it is from book Algebraic Geometric Codes: Basic Notions by Serge Vladut, Dmitry Nogin

Comment: @Alon Amit. Nope, i have read definition of divisor, but not really understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find that book in our library so I need to guess the meaning of the divisor of a form on a curve. I assume that it means that each point in the intersection of the projective curves
$$
X^3Y+Y^3Z+Z^3X=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad Z=0
$$
is multiplied by some kind of intersection multiplicity. I further guess that this multiplicity is defined by calculating the (exponential) valuation of the defining function of the latter curve at a point of intersection (or, more precisely, in the local ring).

So here we can see $Q_1=(1:0:0)$ as the origin $u=v=0$, where $u=Y/X$ and $v=Z/X$ are
the affine coordinates on this piece. This affine piece of the Klein quartic is defined by the equation $P(u,v)=u+u^3v+v^3=0$. Also, in this piece $X=1$, so $Z=v$ (this is admittedly shady - hopefully an algebraic geometer can comment eventually). The partial derivative $\partial P/\partial u=1+3u^2v+3v^2$ does not vanish at $Q_1$, so we can use $v-v(Q_1)=v-0=v$ as a local parameter. So if we denote by $\nu_1$ the discrete valuation at $Q_1$, we have $\nu_1(v)=1$. Therefore the point $Q_1$ appears with multiplicity 1.

With $Q_2$ we need to go to the affine piece $Y=1$, and use affine coordinates $r=X/Y$ and
$s=Z/Y$. The equation of the quartic then becomes $R(r,s)=r^3+s+s^3r=0$. As above we see that $r$ is a local variable at $Q_2$. If $\nu_2$ is the corresponding valuation, we thus have $\nu_2(r)=1$. The form $Z$ agrees with the function $s$ on this affine plane, so we need to compute $\nu_2(s)$. Because $s$ vanishes at $Q_2$, we know that $\nu_2(s)\ge 1$. The equation of the curve gives us the relation
$$
3=\nu_2(r^3)=\nu_2(s+s^3r).
$$
Here $\nu_2(s^3r)=3\cdot\nu_2(s)+\nu_2(r)\ge 4$, so by the non-archimedean triangle inequality we must have $\nu_2(s)=3$.

All this suggests that the divisor you are looking for really is, indeed, $1\cdot Q_1+3\cdot Q_2$.
Unfortunately it is impossible for me to check that this calculation is a valid answer in view of what has been covered in your book up to this point.

Comment: @Lahtonen Thanks! I have found the book on the web!
link to this book added to the topic.
I don't really understand what  kind of divisor that they mean by this question.
Exercise is on page  248 (Namely exercises 4.451,4.452, 4.453).
I have searched the right definition of divisor by index it but not sure that i have found it...:(